# custom javascript does not trigger when clicked on html option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few links, when one of them is clicked, such as "epic", then every div that has that same class name will remain and the others will get filtered out.

Usually it works but im trying out a new system. Instead of clicking links I want the beforementioned to be triggered when I click on a option. Unfortunately it does not work. The elements associated with the data-filters are not filtered. When working with links however it works splendid:

you can see the function in action at a site im testing for a friend: http://rolfvohs.com/

I assume the issue is  **e(".filter-buttons option").click(function() {** although I am not sure why. Maybe im missing something.

I would be happy for some answers as im very desperate already. I cant figure this out.

```
 <select class="cd-select">
                        <option value="-1" selected>Pick a Genre</option>
                        <option value="1" data-filter="*">All</option>
                        <option value="2" data-filter=".epic">Epic</option>
                        <option value="3" data-filter=".classic">Classic</option>
                        <option value="4" data-filter=".pop">Pop</option>
                        <option value="5" data-filter=".rock">Rock</option>
                    </select>
```

My custom javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

        var t = e("#filter-container");
        t.imagesLoaded(function() {
            t.isotope({
                itemSelector: "figure",
                filter: "*",
                resizable: false,
                animationEngine: "jquery"
            })
        });
       $("select").on("change", function() {
            var n = e(this).parents(".filter-buttons");
            var r = e(this).attr("data-filter");
            t.isotope({
                filter: r
            });
            return false
        });
        e(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
            e(this).next().toggle("slow");
            e(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false
        }).next().hide();
        e(window).resize(function() {
            var n = e(window).width();
            t.isotope("reLayout")
        }).trigger("resize")
    })
```

Comment: options do not have click events in all browsers. Use onchange on the select.

Comment: @epascarello hello epascarello. What do you mean onchange? Can you show me an example?

Comment: `$("select").on("change", function() { console.log($(this).val()); } );`

Comment: Becase "this" is not the option so there is no data attribute

Comment: @epascarello updated my code. If you have a look at the function now, did I add it correctly? I replaced the function with onchange function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options do not have a click event in most browsers. You need to listen for the change event on the select.

Based on the comment in the discussion, updated code

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var select = $(this);
    var selectedOption = select.find("option:selected");
    var n = select.parents(".filter-buttons");
    var r = selectedOption.attr("data-filter");
    t.isotope({
      filter: r
    });
    return false
});
```

Comment: I will try it out now and let you know

Comment: It works. Dear epascarello, if you dont mind could you explain the differences and what they do?

Comment: Difference? It selects the option tag to get the data attribute, you were looking at the select.

Comment: I studied it and read about it and it makes sense now. The change works perfectly, unfortunately im using a dropdown plugin that somehow inhibits the new function. It also uses onchange functions but differently. Any way to overide that? Im going to make a seperate question regarding the matter

Comment: It seems this function from the plugin is conflicting:

 this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
    if( self.opened ) {
     var opt = $( this );
     self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
     self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );
     self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
     self.close();
    }
   } );